# Input Embeddings to BERT

Tags: word2vec, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

According to theory, BERT takes word embeddings and position embeddings as input. My goal is to feed the BERT model with word embeddings from a different model like word2vec or Glove.
Is there a way to feed static word embedding to BERT to get contextualized Word embedding from BERT finally?
Please let me know about any relevant links

Comment: You have a conceptual mismatch. BERT uses embeddings for sub-word tokens, while GloVe and word2vec use embeddings for words.

Comment: Hey, I got this idea from a paper. https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.12684. They are passing word embedding to BERT. Can you give it a look at tell me what you think?